# Setting up 802.3ad for true 2Gb/s link aggregation

Tags: networking, server

I have been trying for a few days and reading many posts/resources online but am getting nowhere... I have found so many frustratingly unanswered topics such as - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1572502 or http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1572502 .

Basically, I have a load of switches with 1GB uplinks and we have successfully enabled Link Aggregation between many of the bottlenecks and see 2Gb/s (-overhead) being sent across the links.

I have a server hosting items that constantly is at 100% network utilisation. Long term plan is to move to 10Gb Nics, but, that won't happen for a while.

I have followed every guide I can find about 802.3ad support and I am basically in the same state as this post - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1572502 ... I have fault tolerance in that I can bring either eth0 or eth1 down and the other will immediately pick up, however, I just can't seem to get more than 944Mb/s to be sent or received.

Can anyone help?

Comment: @BaileyS Any hints at what I should be looking at? I have been trying everything I can find - 802.11ad and I think it is working as it is certainly fault tolerant (for what I have tested), but, I just can't get inbound load balancing to work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the switch is playing along if the failover works.

What is your setting for `bond-mode` in `/etc/networking/interfaces`?

I bet it is `bond-mode active-backup`, which only provides failover.

Try changing it to `bond-mode balance-rr` which does load balancing.